# implement efficient search in a skip list

Tags: java

I need to write a code that finds element x in a skip list.
I need to implement that in O(logk) expected running time, where k is the location of x at the list (i.e., there are k-1 elements before x in the list).

So, that's what I know to do so far (pseudo code), but the running time is O(logn), because it goes on the height of the list. how can I improve that to O(logk)?

(p is initialized to be the top most left element in the list)

[image: my implement]

Comment: You may want to show your code to get the discussion started.

Comment: That looks like linear search for a linked list, nothing to do with a skip list.

Comment: You can get the skipList searching algorithm from [here](http://eternallyconfuzzled.com/tuts/datastructures/jsw_tut_skip.aspx)
these are written in _C_ but algorithm is the same. **try the algorithm** and post your code **if couldn't get it right**

Comment: Thanks, but these algorithm don't work for me (or that I just don't see how they solve my problem). can you show me the way, even with general description?